# Exact value of an integral

Tags: integration

I have a problem with getting the exact value of this integral :
$$\int_{x}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-t}}{t}dt$$

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at this http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5BExp%5B-t%5D%2Ft%2C%7Bt%2Cx%2Cinf%7D%5D

Comment: I downvoted because "*I need it as soon as possible*" is **not** what I want to see on this site.

Comment: @Asaf: is it really necessary to downvote a person how uses MSE for the first time even if this person is not doing things in the right way? Remember, that first downvote attracts downvoters

Comment: @Ilya: When someone needs help, they ask for it. They don't write "I need it as soon as possible".

Comment: Bassem, welcome to Math.SE. Whenever you ask a question please provide as much info as possible on what you have done, where you got the problem from etc. Also, try to be polite - people are here to help you and are often willing to do so.

Comment: @Asaf: Maybe you regard OP's "I need it as soon as possible" as a claim that we *have to* answer his question asap. I regard it as the need OP have and don't assume he thinks I *have to* do anything. All in all, I think that before downvoting the question, such comment as AD should be better appreciated.

Comment: @Ilya: Nothing I will tell you will make you change your stand on these things, and nothing you will tell me will make me change my stand on these things. I also think that in the long run it does not matter too much either. We can agree to disagree, and if you want nicer comments to these sort of posts - feel free to outrace me to them.

Comment: @Asaf: I certainly agree to disagree and I do respect your point of view. Just wanted to warn you about cascades of downvoters caused by a 1st downvote to questions of new users, asked not in the lines of MSE. Challenge to outrace is accepted, but I won't take it serious, so most likely you win :) anyway, I respect your point of view and don't want to convince you I'm right.

Comment: I hope the answer below satisfied the OP's ASAP. He sounded really bossy and that's spooky...And Ilya: if a first poster doesn't even have the courtesy to add "please" then he's going to learn the hard way that he must be more polite. After all, it's with H.S. students and up that we're dealing here. not with toddlers or little kids.

Comment: Thank you for you remarks. I am really sorry for let you feel that i am not polite. But, it s juste my first time to post on.

Answer (score 5):

Did you try WolframAlpha?

```
integrate e^(-t)/t, t=x..infinity
```

yields $\log (x)+\Gamma (0,x)$ for $x>0$.  When a result is specified in terms of a special function like this, it's probably not exactly computable.  Nonetheless, you can generate numerical approximations easily enough.

```
log(x) + gamma(0,x) at x=3
```

or look at a plot

```
plot log(x) + gamma(0,x)
```

[image]

Comment: What's $\Gamma(0,x)$?  Is it the same as $\Gamma(x)$?

Comment: @user20520 If you enter the code I suggested, you'll see that $\Gamma(a,x)$ refers to the incomplete Gamma function and you'll see pointers to more information.

Comment: Thank you for you remarks. I am really sorry for let you feel that i am not polite. But, it s juste my first time to post on.

Comment: @Bassem No, no, not at all! I just think that it is generally useful to point out to someone how they might find things out for themselves in the future - and I'm certainly not one of the downvoters of the question, either.